# Which syntax is more typical to React, if any (version 16)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

I'm very new to React and I see a lot of examples with slight variations of syntax. Due to my ignorance and incompetence, I can't tell which ones are more proper and which ones are creations of people as confused as I am. Also, I can imagine that the variations are due to different version of the library.

I do understand the difference between the following two examples **in JS terms** but I wonder if any strikes as less proper for a React application. Or, possibly, if no one can tell and it's perfectly acceptable to go either way.

**The explicit import**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render, version }  from "react-dom";
import MainArea from "./components/MainArea";

const ver = version;
render(<MainArea />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

**The implicit import**

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MainArea from "./components/MainArea";

const ver = ReactDOM.version;
ReactDOM.render(<MainArea />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: they're both fine

Comment: Both work the same. Use whichever you like better. (You might prefer namespace imports if you have very many imports and are not familiar with what each module exports).

Comment: I think that the first one makes more sense, since you're only importing what you need.

Comment: @Anas No, there's really no difference. Both load the same modules, and both can be tree-shaken the same.

Comment: @Bergi Didn't know that tree-shaking will work on both, Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Bergi but importing more keywords into the global scope will limit the number of names you could use to create new variable or import another package that contains the same module name...

Comment: @mxdi9i7 It's the module scope, not the global scope. And yes, you would of course need to use aliases to prevent collisions, but it's not a problem in the code the OP posted. Also it's why I said that namespace imports can help with keeping track of everything…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen and used both styles of imports. I tend to to prefer implicit imports for code that I'm actively changing. You don't have to repeat yourself when it comes to adding things in the module you've imported.

For example, replacing

```
import {
    action1,
    action2,
    ...,
    actionN
} from './actions';
```

with

```
import * as actions from './actions';
```

means you only need to add an action in `./actions.js` rather than add the action, then explicitly refer to it.

As a rule of thumb: prefer explicit imports where the module in question doesn't change often, and prefer implicit imports where there are >3 names imported into the namespace, or you anticipate regular changes to that module.